# Mongoose populate after save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I cannot manually or automatically populate the creator field on a newly saved object ... the only way I can find is to re-query for the objects I already have which I would hate to do.

This is the setup:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
  name: String,
});
var User = db.model('User', userSchema);

var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  description: String,
});
var Book = db.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

This is where I am pulling my hair

```
var user = new User();
user.save(function(err) {
    var book = new Book({
        _creator: user,
    });
    book.save(function(err){
        console.log(book._creator); // is just an object id
        book._creator = user; // still only attaches the object id due to Mongoose magic
        console.log(book._creator); // Again: is just an object id
        // I really want book._creator to be a user without having to go back to the db ... any suggestions?
    });
});
```

EDIT: latest mongoose fixed this issue and added populate functionality, see the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You should be able to use the Model's populate function to do this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate  In the save handler for book, instead of:

```
book._creator = user;
```

you'd do something like:

```
Book.populate(book, {path:"_creator"}, function(err, book) { ... });
```

Probably too late an answer to help you, but I was stuck on this recently, and it might be useful for others.

Comment: It would be nice if this worked with virtual attributes. like `creator.profile`

Comment: if user has some virtual attributes they are not included.

Comment: This worked for me although I had some problems when I tried to set the reference to null just before I saved. After the save, calling Book.populate incorrectly populated the field with the previous reference value and I can't work out why. The DB successfully contains the null.

Comment: And this will **not** re-query the database?!

Comment: this is re-querying the database

Comment: Are we suppose to see the whole object or just the object id after saving? I only seem to get objectId('3g3d445555fffff')?

Comment: For those that want to stay away from callbacks, here's an [alternative solution which returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600472/2757916).

Answer (score 52):

The solution for me was to use `execPopulate`, like so

```
const t = new MyModel(value)
return t.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path').execPopulate())
```

### Update

**Mongoose 6.X and up:** `.execPopulate()` is [removed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate) and `.populate()` is no longer chainable

The above code should be written like:

```js
const t = new MyModel(value)
return t.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path')) // Returns a promise
```

If you don't want a promise:

```js
return t.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path')).then(t => t)
```

Since it is no longer chainable, the new way to populate multiple fields is to use an array or an object:

```js
return t.save().then(t => t.populate(['my-path1', 'my-path2'])).then(t => t)
```

Resources:

- [Gets _id(s) used during population of the given `path`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.populated())
- [All of the ways to use population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population)
- [Read in-depth about each populate API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/search.html?q=populate)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Francois , You saved my life , I was trying to find solution for this . FInally got that.

Comment: Saved my life as well. Wish you all the best, you rock!

Answer (score 37):

In case that anyone is still looking for this.

Mongoose 3.6 has introduced a lot of cool features to populate:

```
book.populate('_creator', function(err) {
 console.log(book._creator);
});
```

or:

```
Book.populate(book, '_creator', function(err) {
 console.log(book._creator);
});
```

see more at: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#population

But this way you would still query for the user again.

A little trick to accomplish it without extra queries would be:

```
book = book.toObject();
book._creator = user;
```

Comment: doing `book._creator = user;` after the `save()` is the only correct answer among all the current answers, all other answers require an additional query.

Answer (score 29):

### The solution which returns a promise (no callbacks):

**Use Document#populate**

```
// These two are same
book.populate('creator').exec();
book.populate('creator');

// summary
doc.populate(options).exec(); // returns a promise
doc.populate(options) // returns promise
```

**Possible Implementation**

```
var populatedDoc = doc.populate(options);
populatedDoc.then(doc => {
   ... 
});
```

The `.exec()` method is used on queries to return a true promise, since queries do not return true promises, they are just thenable values that work with await. But using it on `.populate()` changes nothing, `.populate()` returns a promise, since [Mongoose 6.X](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate). You can see `.exec()` used alongside `.populate()` on the [official site](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

What exactly `.exec()` does has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

Read about document population [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate).

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks

Comment: IDK you know or not, but this code is just a syntax sugar. It will sends a new query to the database. So this is not a good answer.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer for Mongoose 6.X and up. Please update the answer.

Comment: @luzede, would you mind updating the answer if/when you find a solution?

Answer (score 15):

I thought I'd add to this to clarify things for complete noobs like myself.

What's massively confusing if you're not careful is that there are three very different populate methods. They are methods of different objects (Model vs. Document), take different inputs and give different outputs (Document vs. Promise).

Here they are for those that are baffled:

### Document.prototype.populate()

[See full docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)

This one works on documents and returns a document. In the original example, it would look like this:

```
book.save(function(err, book) {
    book.populate('_creator', function(err, book) {
        // Do something
    })
});
```

Because it works on documents and returns a document, you can chain them together like so:

```
book.save(function(err, book) {
    book
    .populate('_creator')
    .populate('/* Some other ObjectID field */', function(err, book) {
        // Do something
    })
});
```

But don't be silly, like me, and try to do this:

```
book.save(function(err, book) {
    book
    .populate('_creator')
    .populate('/* Some other ObjectID field */')
    .then(function(book) {
        // Do something
    })
});
```

Remember: Document.prototype.populate() returns a document, so this is nonsense. If you want a promise, you need...

### Document.prototype.execPopulate()

[See full docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate)

This one works on documents BUT it returns a promise that resolves to the document.
In other words, you can use it like this:

```
book.save(function(err, book) {
    book
    .populate('_creator')
    .populate('/* Some other ObjectID field */')
    .execPopulate()
    .then(function(book) {
        // Do something
    })
});
```

That's better. Finally, there's...

### Model.populate()

[See full docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)

This one **works on models** and returns a promise. It's therefore used a bit differently:

```
book.save(function(err, book) {
    Book // Book not book
    .populate(book, { path: '_creator'})
    .then(function(book) {
        // Do something
    })
});
```

Hope that's helped some other newcomers.

Comment: The example looks straightforward but what exactly is the purpose of {path: ':_createor'}? Is _creator related to the OPs' example? If my document has several properties like _Id, Id, title or year - which would be used for path? The equivalent of the primary key?

Comment: This answer is outdated, the .populate() method now returns a promise, but is not chainable, it accepts an array of paths, object or a string to do the population. .execPopulate() is deprecated and removed. All these after Mongoose 6.X and up. [information about the updates](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate)

Answer (score 12):

Just to elaborate and give another example, as it helped me out. This might help those who want to to retrieve partially populated objects after save. The method is slightly different as well. Spent more than an hour or two looking for the correct way to do it.

```
  post.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(500, {
        error: 'Cannot save the post'
      });
    }
    post.populate('group', 'name').populate({
      path: 'wallUser',
      select: 'name picture'
    }, function(err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me

```
    let post = await PostModel.create({
        ...req.body, author: userId
    })

    post = await post.populate('author', 'name')

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: { post }
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. Just keep in mind that this code maybe looks great but what it is doing is sending another query to database. So your code is just a little sugar and shorter. You can enable debug mode and see the generated queries

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly this is a long standing issue with mongoose which I believe is not solved yet:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/570

What you can do is to write you own custom getter/setter ( and set *real* `_customer` in a seperate property ) for this. For example:

```
var get_creator = function(val) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty( "__creator" )) {
        return this.__creator;
    }
    return val;
};
var set_creator = function(val) {
    this.__creator = val;
    return val;
};
var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _creator: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'User',
     get: get_creator,
     set: set_creator
  },
  description: String,
});
```

**NOTE:** I didn't test it and it might work strangely with `.populate` and when setting pure id.

Comment: it seems they are not looking to fix the issue.

Comment: this issue is fixed in 3.6

Comment: @Pykler you really need to change the accepted answer to the highest rated one before, as this answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose 5.2.7

This works for me (just a lot of headache !)

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
  const author = req.userData;
  const postInfo = new Post({
    author,
    content: req.body.content,
    isDraft: req.body.isDraft,
    status: req.body.status,
    title: req.body.title
  });
  postInfo.populate('author', '_id email role display_name').execPopulate();
  postInfo.save()
    .then(post => {
      res.status(200).json(post);
    }).catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoose 6.x you can simply do:

```
const t = await MyModel.create(value).then((t) =>
  t.populate('my-path')
);
```

The `execPopulate()` method has now been removed.

Answer (score 1):

The way populate worked for me using **async/await** was:

```js
const updatedBook = await book.save()
const populatedBook = await updatedBook.populate('field', { name: 1, author: 1, field3: 1})
```

where `fieldName: 1` tells with what fields from 'field' to populate.

With **promises** it would probably be like:

```js
book.save()
  .then(savedBook => savedBook.populate())
  .then(populatedBook => populatedBook)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably sth. like

```
Book.createAsync(bookToSave).then((savedBook) => savedBook.populateAsync("creator"));
```

Would be the nicest and least problematic way to make this work (Using Bluebird promises).

Answer (score 0):

ended up writing some curry-able Promise functions where you declare your schema, query_adapter, data_adapter functions and populate string in advance. For a shorter / simpler implementation easier on.

It's probably not super efficient, but I thought the execution bit was quite elegant.

github file: [curry_Promises.js](https://github.com/wouldBeNerd/mongoose_methods/blob/master/curry_Promises.js)

**declartion**

```
const update_or_insert_Item = mDB.update_or_insert({
    schema : model.Item,
    fn_query_adapter : ({ no })=>{return { no }},
    fn_update_adapter : SQL_to_MDB.item,
    populate : "headgroup"
    // fn_err : (e)=>{return e},
    // fn_res : (o)=>{return o}
})
```

**execution**

```
Promise.all( items.map( update_or_insert_Item ) )
.catch( console.error )
.then( console.log )
```

Answer (score 0):

Save document in model and then populate

```
   chatRoom = await chatRoom.save();
   const data = await chatRoom
  .populate("customer", "email dp")
  .populate({
    path: "admin",
    select: "name logo",
  })
  .execPopulate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me so I saved and then used findById to get that data with populate back again

```
const data: any = await Model.findById(id)
  .populate("name")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not adding anything new here.

It's just a cleaner way of writing this using async/await:

```
const newCourse = new Course(new_course_data);
const populate_options = [
  // Here write your populate options
];
const created_course = await newCourse.save();
await created_course.populate(populate_options).execPopulate();
```

Comment: node:30332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: .populate(...).execPopulate is not a function