# Mongoose - What does the exec function do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I came across a piece of Mongoose code that included a query findOne and then an exec() function.

Ive never seen that method in Javascript before? What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Basically when using mongoose, documents can be retrieved using helpers. Every model method that accepts query conditions can be executed by means of a `callback` or the `exec` method.

`callback`:

```
User.findOne({ name: 'daniel' }, function (err, user) {
  //
});
```

`exec`:

```
User
  .findOne({ name: 'daniel' })
  .exec(function (err, user) {
      //
  });
```

Therefore when you don't pass a callback you can build a query and eventually execute it.

You can find additional info in the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

**UPDATE**

Something to note when using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in combination with Mongoose async operations is that Mongoose queries are **not** Promises. Queries do return a *thenable*, but if you need a *real* Promise you should use the `exec` method. More information can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

During the update I noticed I didn't explicitly answer the question:

> Ive never seen that method in Javascript before? What does it do
>   exactly?

Well it's **not** a native JavaScript method, but part of the Mongoose API.

Comment: What if I have set mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird'), do I still need to use .exec() ? Thanks.

Comment: @wayofthefuture I find the docs really confusing about this matter, but I believe you still need to call the `exec` method. This is what they do in the docs at least. To be sure you can check yourself with `Model.find() instanceof require('bluebird')`. Hope this helps.

Comment: And then there is the question of other operations such as delete and insertMany... would exec() be necessary in these cases? Delete would have to use some kind of query underneath the hood...

Comment: exec also returns a promise, if no callback is passed, which is very convenient I must say

Comment: *It might save someone*. If you think that Model.update() will do its job and don't wait for some not-so-important data to be updated and return response to the API; Your update won't execute. You need to `Model.update().exec()` to make sure it will execute. Then you can respond to the api without waiting for update.

Comment: Is it possible to do a .find({}) query and then execute it later? Like `const query = await Model.find({});` and then later `query.exec();` ?

Answer (score 127):

I never use `exec()` function to complete a CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) on a model. When I want CRUD on a model, I use it like this:

```js
const user = await UserModel.findOne(userCondition);
```

And it always does the job. So I wondered "what does `exec()` use for"?
As I searched in mongoose document, I found the answer [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

> Should You Use exec() With await?

And here is the story.
You have two ways to execute a query on a model. Using `callback` or using `exec()` function. "But" you can use `await` too. `exec()` function returns a promise, that you can use it with `then()` or `async/await` to execute a query on a model "asynchronous". So the question is "If I can just use `user = await UserModel.find()` and it works currectly, so why should I use `exec()` function?". The answer that you can find in the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) is: 
There are two difference between using `await` with `exec()` or without it.

- As a functionality point of view, there is no difference between using `await` with `exec()` or without it. Just when you call a query without `exec()` or `callback`, it returns a `thenable` which is something like promise but it's not a promise.(You can find the difference [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)). But when you use `exec()` to run a query, you get exactly a promise as response.

```
// returns a thenable as response that is not a promise, but you can use await and then() with it.
const user = await UserModel.findOne(userCondition);

// returns exactly a promise.
const user = await UserModel.findOne(userCondition).exec();
```

- Another difference is, if you use `await` with `exec()` you get a better "stack trace" if you catch any error in executing queries. So:
  These two line, do the same thing:

```
const user = await UserModel.findOne(userCondition);

// does exactly as the before line does, but you get a better stack trace if any error happened
const user = await UserModel.findOne(userCondition).exec();
```

Comment: Very important difference! When testing my queries I noticed that when I distorted on purpose the format of _id field in the url to test for error, the try / catch was not picking the error and my models was issuing the deprecated warning, that promises that return errors that are not catched won't be accommodated any more in the future.

Comment: "As far as functionality is concerned, these two are equivalent. However, we recommend using .exec() because that gives you better stack traces." [Direct docs  ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await).

Comment: is this recommended with all of the await mongoose operations? I mean await user.deleteOne() too.

Comment: What a great answer! The MongoDB documentation for findOneAndUpdate states "The query executes if callback is passed else a Query object is returned" but doesn't mention anything about using it with then() or async/await. This explains why I wasn't seeing this method return a Query object: I was using 'await'.

Answer (score 82):

Daniel has answered this quite beautifully. To elaborate on an exhaustive list of ways to build and execute queries, look at the following use cases:

**Query Building**

Mongoose will not execute a query until `then` or `exec` has been called upon it. This is very useful when building complex queries. Some examples can include using the `populate` and `aggregate` functions.

```
User.find({name: 'John'}) // Will not execute
```

**Execution via callback**

Although disliked by many due to its nesting nature, queries can be executed by providing the optional callback.

```
User.find({name: 'John'}, (err, res) => {}) // Will execute
```

**Then API as a Promises/A+**

Mongoose queries do provide a `then` function. This is not to be confused with regular promises. Simply put, the Promises/A+ specification requires a `then` function to work much like how we're used to with promises.

```
User.find({name: 'John'}).then(); // Will execute
Promise.all([User.find({name: 'John'}), User.find({name: 'Bob'})]) // Will execute all queries in parallel
```

**The exec function**

From Mongoose docs `If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.`

```
User.find({name: 'John'}).exec(); // Will execute returning a promise
```

Comment: the docs didn't mention it explicitly but the examples show User.save() returning a promise as well. Apart from exec() and save() do any other mongoose methods on the model return a promise, or is it just these two?

Comment: As pointed above, you can use `then` on a query to return a promise too. This isn't much different than `exec`. The use case I find this handy is when using something like `Promise.all`. Not sure if the promise returned by `exec` works in such contexts though.

Comment: Can you please add a complete example with .exec() ? @AnshulKoka Is it that the .exec() automatically makes the query asynchronous or should i add async/await

Comment: Making the query asynchronous will require async/await so I'm not sure if I understand the question. Just prefix await to my example for your request for a complete example.

Comment: See here for explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457247/3904109

Comment: The `Promise.all` example is probably too simplistic, as you should use `find(name: { $in: ['John', 'Bob'] })` instead

Answer (score 11):

`exec()` will return a promise if no callback is provided. So the following pattern is very convenient and generic - it can handle callbacks or promises nicely:

```
function findAll(query, populate, cb) {

  let q = Response.find(query);

  if (populate && populate.length > 0) {
    q = q.populate(populate);
  }

  // cb is optional, will return promise if cb == null
  return q.lean().exec(cb);

}
```

I recommend using Bluebird promises with Mongoose, to do that, use this call:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Comment: why do we need bluebird ? when we have exec()

Comment: (We don't, at least not now that promises are a mature ES spec, and if supporting semi-modern browsers.)

Answer (score 3):

all answers are correct but the easiest way is to use modern async await approach..

```
async ()=> {
const requiresUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,{name:'noname'},{ new:true}).exec()
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, mongoose queries do not return any promise. So that if we want them to queries work like a promise we use the exec function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32522514)

Answer (score 1):

One way to get data:

```
find().exec((err,data)=>{

})
```

Other way:

```
const res=await find()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok i'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

**2023 update**

Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback

Use following pattern:

```
const result = await Model.findOne({filter:filter}).exec();
return result ;

**or**

const x = await Model.findOne({filter:filter}).exec()
.then((data)=>{
   return (data);
}).catch((err)=> {
     return (err);
});
```