# Proper use of asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i wanna know when to use exec or then, and what's the difference

```
Schema.findOne({_id:id}).then(function(obj){
//do somthing
})
```

or to use exec

```
Schema.findOne({_id:id}).exec().then(function(obj){
//do somthing
})
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

Answer (score 0):

Some methods of Mongoose returns a query but not execute others execute directly.

When returns only a query use exec().

'then' is used as promise handler after execution.

You can use 'then and catch' or callback after execution.

There is an example using promise and the same using  callback.

```
Cat.find({})
  .select('name age') // returns a query 
  .exec() // execute query
  .then((cats) => {

  })
  .catch((err) => {

  });

Cat.find({})
  .select('name age') // returns a query 
  .exec((err,cats) => { // execute query and callback
     if(err){

     } else {

     }
  });
```

Now lets make same without query(don't select fields, don't need to exec, because is already exec)

```
Cat.find({})
  .then((cats) => {

  })
  .catch((err) => {

  });

Cat.find({}, (err,cats) => {
     if(err){

     } else {

     }
  });
```