# Using mongoose promises with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to get the hang of using Mongoose promises with the async/await functionality of Node.js. When my function `printEmployees` is called I want to save the list of employees which are queried by the `orderEmployees` function. While, the `console.log` statement inside `orderEmployees` returns the expected query, the `console.log` inside of `printEmployees` returns `undefined`, suggesting that I'm not returning the promise correctly.

I'm new to promises so entirely possible that I'm not correctly understanding the paradigm... any help is much appreciated.

```
  printEmployees: async(company) => {
    var employees = await self.orderEmployees(company);
    // SECOND CONSOLE.LOG
    console.log(employees);
  },

  orderEmployees: (companyID) => {
    User.find({company:companyID})
    .exec()
    .then((employees) => {
      // FIRST CONSOLE.LOG
      console.log(employees);
      return employees;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return 'error occured';
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) your [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

- Currently, you are awaiting on a function that returns `undefined`.
- `await` only actually "waits" for the value if it's used with a `Promise`.
- Always keep in mind that [you can only `await` Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or [`async functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which implicitly return a `Promise`<sup>1</sup>.

---

```
orderEmployees: (companyID) => {
  return User.find({ company:companyID }).exec()
}
```

Also really important, you should `throw` instead of `return` in your `.catch` handler. Returning from within a `.catch` handler will cause the promise chain to trigger it's `.then` instead of it's `.catch` thus breaking the error handling chain.

Better yet, don't include `.catch` at all and let the the actual error bubble up the promise chain, instead of overriding it with your own non-descriptive `'error occured'` message.

Error conditions should throw the error, not return it.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can also await non-Promises, but only for values that are evaluated synchronously.

Answer (score 49):

In order to make `orderEmployees` behave like async functions, you have to return the resulting promise. There are two rules to follow when using promises without `async/await` keywords:

1. A function is asynchronous if it returns a `Promise`
2. If you have a promise (for example returned by an async function) you must either call `.then` on it or return it.

When you are using `async/await` then you **must** `await` on promises you obtain.

This said you will notice that you do not return the promise generated inside `orderEmployees`. Easy to fix, but its also easy to rewrite that function to async too.

```
orderEmployees: (companyID) => {
  return User.find({company:companyID}) // Notice the return here
  .exec()
  .then((employees) => {
    // FIRST CONSOLE.LOG
    console.log(employees);
    return employees;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return 'error occured';
  });
},
```

or

```
orderEmployees: async(companyID) => {
  try {
    const employees = await User.find({company:companyID}).exec();
    console.log(employees);
    return employees;
  } catch (err) {
    return 'error occured';
  }
},
```

PS: the error handling is somewhat flawed here. We usually do not handle errors by returning an error string from a function. It is better to have the error propagate in this case, and handle it from some top-level, UI code.

Comment: Hi can you do async(companyID) => {
   await User.find({company:companyID}).then(data =>{
   return data
}).catch(err => {
   return err.message
})
}

Comment: @ODaneBrissett What's the question exactly? The code you wrote has many problems, it wouldn't work. Technically you can mix await and then, but I would advise against it as it is easy to get it wrong. Just use async await. `try { return await User.find(); } catch(e) { showerror(e.message); // dont return the error message, you never want to do that }`

Comment: I was just seeking clarification to see if my approach would work. But thanks for your input. Can you say why it wouldn't work

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett I noticed 4 things, 1: that async function does not return anything 2: `.then(data =>{ return data })` doesn't do anything, it just evaluates to a similar promise with the same resolution value, 3: `.catch(err => { return err.message })` will hide the exception, makes handling errors impossible, 4: a red flag is that there is no await in an async function

Comment: Hmm interesting thanks for that, however, this is my full implementation below and it works
`exports.getLoan = async (req, res) => {
  await Loans.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(data => {
      if (!data) return res.status(404).send('Sponsored product not found')

      res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message })
    })
}`

Just one of the methods in a controller. I tested and it catches the error plus returns the response. I just want to know if there's any faults in this approach

Comment: That should work fine although it has an unnecessary return statement in catch, and unnecessary async and await. Remove those and replace await with return and the code will work the same. But that means you take a step back instead of forward, the state of the art way would be to eliminate all the thens and using use async and await

Comment: So when I remove the then, i should just wrap it in try catch and return the results in a const like so: `router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const customers = await Customer.find().sort('name')

    res.send(customers)
  }catch{
    //What ever code
  }
})`

And based on what you're saying is the same thing?

Comment: Ohhh Okay. My original thought  is that the previous code does the same thing but in a more elegant way. Also, is the .exec() really necessary at in my implementation above? given that there's no additional callback?

Comment: I don't know, as the question is rather about promises and not really about Mongoose I did not look up the documentation. But you should!

Comment: Yeaaa. Thanks for the input tho. much appreciated

Comment: `.exec()` was my missing part. thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning a Promise from orderEmployees.

```
printEmployees: async(company) => {
  var employees = await self.orderEmployees(company);
  // SECOND CONSOLE.LOG
  console.log(employees);
},

orderEmployees: (companyID) => {
  return User.find({company:companyID})
 .exec()
 .then((employees) => {
   // FIRST CONSOLE.LOG
   console.log(employees);
   return employees;
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   return 'error occured';
 });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a `Promise` from `orderEmployees`

```
orderEmployees: companyId => User.find({ companyId }).exec()
```

If you want to do some error handling or pre-processing before you return then you can keep your code as is but just remember to return the result (promises are chainable).

Comment: I dont see how the [explicit promise creation antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) would help with error handling. What is the benefit? You could just `return employees` and `throw e` from a simple async function.

Comment: @TamasHegedus yeah good point, old habit from times where Node didn't handle throwing exceptions well from inside promises!

Answer (score 3):

if you're going to use async/await then it works like this.

- await in front of the function that returns a promise.
- async in front of the wrapping function.
- wrap the function body inside try/catch block.

Please have a look on this function, it is a middleware
before i execute a specific route in express.

```
const validateUserInDB = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findById(req.user._id);
        if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized." });
        req.user = user;
        return next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error." })
    }
}
```

- The code after await is waiting the promise to be resolved.
- **Catch block catches any error** happened inside the try block even if the error that is triggered by catch method comes from awaiting promise.