# how to return the value of find method in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I try to define function that gets email as input value and returns the status of user whether its exists or not with this email , but actully I`m not able to return the value via find method from mongoose model which is User here! this is my code :

```
const User = require('./models/user')

// checking if user with this email exists or not and return true if it exists
function isExists(email) {
    return User.findOne({email : email})
        .then(user =>{
            if(!user){
                return false 
            }
            return true
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)
        })
}

let status = isExists('example@example.com') 
console.log(status);
```

also I tried other way but it didn`t work :

```
async function getUser(email) {
    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({email : email})
        return user ; 
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
let user = await getUser('example@example.com')
console.log(user);
```

In all of these approaches I try to return value of find method to other variable but none of them work correctly and I dont know why? I think the main problem is my understanding of logic of promises and async/await

Comment: let user = await getUser('example@example.com') remove the await here... and you should get the result

Comment: I remove it but the result is : Promise { <pending> }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457247/10431732