# the 'findIndex' is undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript

In nodejs the findIndex is undefined

```
let userCart = db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).findOne({user:objectId(userId)})
            if (userCart){
                let proExist=userCart.products.findIndex(product=> product.item==proId)
                console.log(proExist);
            }
```

in my console it says:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined
at C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Projects\E-Commerce Application\helpers\user-helper.js:49:48
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.addToCart (C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Projects\E-Commerce Application\helpers\user-helper.js:46:16)
```

Comment: that's because `userCart.products` is undefined, please make sure it is an array.

Comment: this is because **userCart** do not have any **products** key !

Comment: "_the findIndex is undefined_" That is not what the error says. It tell you that it cannot read `findIndex` _from_ `undefined`. Whatever it tries to perform `findIndex` on is `undefined`.

Comment: My guess is that the first line assigns a Promise to `userCart`, not a cart object. You probably need to `await` the db command.

Answer (score 2):

The error

> Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined

is coming from this line of your code:

`userCart.products.findIndex`

which means that your `userCart` object doesn't contain a property `products`.

Can you please try using `Promise` for the statement to get the data from DB? And in the resolve block, you can add your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Because Mongoose DB operations are `promises`. And you are just trying to read `userCart` as an `object` before the `promise` getting finished.
You should use `await` keyword to wait until the `findOne()` returns the result.

[(Recommended) Using mongoose promises with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457071/using-mongoose-promises-with-async-await)

```
async function something(){
   let userCart = await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).findOne({user:objectId(userId)});
   if (userCart){
        let proExist=userCart.products.findIndex(product=> product.item==proId)
        console.log(proExist);
   }
}
```