# Mongoose .save() only runs 5 times

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a code that maps through my House data seeder with a relation of month, weird thing that happens is it loops through the end but only saves 5 records in the month model

```
    const insertMonths = houses.map((house, i) => {
      const months = new Month({ year: "2021" });
      months.save();
      console.log(i);
      return { ...house, months: months._id };
    });
    await House.insertMany(insertMonths);
```

I don't know what causes this behavior.

Comment: have you considered that months.save() is async and you need to make the map function async?

Comment: Yes, but it errors me out that it can't seem to get the data of each individual house if I use async await

Comment: I've got it to run but it seems that it runs, but it errors out at the end it gives me a validation error for some reason, I used promise.all on the map function
`
    const insertMonths = await Promise.all(
      houses.map(async (house) => {
        const months = new Month({ year: "2021" });
        const finalHouses = { ...house, months: months._id };
        console.log(finalHouses);
        return { finalHouses };
      })
    );
    await House.insertMany(insertMonths);
`

Comment: check this, if it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457071/using-mongoose-promises-with-async-await

Comment: I solved  it using Promise.all I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 0):

I used the Promise.all function

```
    const insertMonths = await Promise.all(
      houses.map(async (house) => {
        const createdHouse = await House.create(house);
        const createdMonth = await Month.create({ year: "2021" });
        const updateHouse = await House.findById(createdHouse);
        updateHouse.yearlyDues.push(createdMonth._id);
        await updateHouse.save();
        const updateMonth = await Month.findById(createdMonth);
        updateMonth.house = createdHouse._id;
        await updateMonth.save();
      })
    );    const insertMonths = await Promise.all(
      houses.map(async (house) => {
        const createdHouse = await House.create(house);
        const createdMonth = await Month.create({ year: "2021" });
        const updateHouse = await House.findById(createdHouse);
        updateHouse.yearlyDues.push(createdMonth._id);
        await updateHouse.save();
        const updateMonth = await Month.findById(createdMonth);
        updateMonth.house = createdHouse._id;
        await updateMonth.save();
      })
    );
```

I don't really know how to it fully works but it lets you get inside the Promise and pinpoint the values or something, edit if I'm wrong.