# Send response after multiple asynchronous queries with mongoose and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I try to make a list with products that I send to the client, but the `res.send` gets executed before the loop has finished. Do you have any suggestions? Async/await doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
const Outfits = require("../models/Outfits");
const Products = require("../models/Products");

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    Outfits.find({ outfitId: req.params.id }, async (error1, result) => {
        if (error1) {
            res.status(400).json({
                status: "fail",
            });
        } else {
            let productIds = result[0].productIds;
            let productList = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
                await Products.find({ id: productIds[i] })
                    .then((product) => {
                        console.log(product);
                        productList.push(product);
                    })
                    .catch((error2) => {
                        res.status(400).json({
                            status: "fail",
                        });
                    });
            }
            console.log(productList);
            res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
                body: productList,
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: few things, `map` doesn't work with `await`, and if it did, you're not returning anything from the `productIds.map` loop.

Comment: I changed the code. The console.log(product) shows the item but the console.log(products) and the products in the res is undefined. The console.log(products) gets executed before console.log(product)

Comment: I think the issue might be with `Products.find`. Are you sure that the method is not async?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @HarshilLaheri when I make it async, I get the error "const err = new MongooseError('Query was already executed: ' + str);"

Comment: Ohh, didn't realise that it is a Mongoose model. In that case it is definitely async. You can use await on that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457071/using-mongoose-promises-with-async-await . This will probably work

Comment: @HarshilLaheri I changed to that but the res.send gets executed before

Comment: Can you share the updated code? You might need to change the `.map` to a for loop and then call `await` on `Products.find`. That should work.

Comment: so, now it works. I changed the code in my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Saw the update, I'm still not sure if this is the right way to do it. Posting an answer with the correct way to use await on .find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have multiple asynchronous tasks executed at once, a cleaner way is to use a `Promise.all` and pass an array of your asynchronous tasks. Like so:

```js
const Outfits = require("../models/Outfits");
const Products = require("../models/Products");

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    Outfits.find({ outfitId: req.params.id }, async (error1, result) => {
        if (error1) {
            res.status(400).json({
                status: "fail",
            });
        } else {
            let productIds = result[0].productIds;
            
            //
            const productList = await Promise.all(
                 productIds.map((id) => Products.findById(id))
            );
           
            console.log(productList);
            res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
                body: productList,
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `await` on the `Products.find` function like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
  try {
    const product = await Products.find({ id: productIds[i] }).exec()
    console.log(product);
    productList.push(product);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any suggestions? Async/await doesn't seem to work

The async/await in your code does not work it is **because of the function mongoose gives you.**

1. callback style

   // finds the outfit and passes the outfit to the callback

   Outfits.find({ outfitId: req.params.id }, async (error1, outfit) => {

   // your other logic

   })
2. async/await style

   // finds the outfit and returns

   const outfit = await Outfits.find({outfitId: req.params.id }).exec();

*Assuming you retrieve array of product id this way*

```
let productIds = result[0].productIds;

const products = await Promise.all(

productIds.map((productId)=>{

   return Products.findById(productId)

}

)
```

*This should retrieve you the list of products*

This is my first time answering a question hence the try hard answer haha :).