# findOneAndUpdate mongoose query returning old database value

Tags: javascript, mongoose

The following is my code snap, I've come across the solution of using {new: true} as an additional argument, but I'm not able to use it with .then() function. I need some way to retreive the updated value.

```
router.post('/profile/:userId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    user: req.body.user,
    education: req.body.education,
    location: req.body.location,
    phone: req.body.phone
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({error: err});
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding .exec() to get a real promise as Mongoose queries do not return a promise.

```
router.post('/profile/:userId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
var query = {};
var update = {
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    user: req.body.user,
    education: req.body.education,
    location: req.body.location,
    phone: req.body.phone
};
var options = {upsert: true, new: true,};
Profile.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .exec()
    .then( result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    })
```

});

Help Link -> [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the options `new: true` in order to get the updated document.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

There is no way ti use this options without a callback function.

Code example:

```
router.post('/profile/:userId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    user: req.body.user,
    education: req.body.education,
    location: req.body.location,
    phone: req.body.phone
  },(err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
      } else {
        console.log(doc);
        res.status(201).json(doc);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: So I'll have to change my whole structure to use callbacks instead of promises?