# Mongoose find vs exec. How to return values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new programming in Node and I'm stuck because I no understand exactly what is the difference between .find and .exec. Here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
exports.getPopulatedUsers = async function(query){
    var res = await users.find(query, function (err, docs) {
       if(err) return err;
       return docs;
   });
    return res; //  **Work fine, res return docs**
}
```

But when execute with .exec the res is undefined.

```
exports.getPopulatedUsers = async function(query){
    var res = await users.find(query).exec(function (err, docs) {
       if(err) return err;
       return docs;
   });
    return res; //  **ERROR, res is undefined **
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148831/6511655

Comment: This can be helpful too http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: thanks, @iofjuupasli. Your link explains a lot about .exec and Promise in Mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix promise with callbacks in mongoose:

```
exports.getPopulatedUsers = async function(query){
    var docs = await users.find(query).exec();
    return docs;
}
```

as for what's the difference between exec and find, read the links in the comment section they are very clear.

Comment: Would you handle errors with `.then()`  `.catch()` ?

Comment: As OP explicitly asked what the difference is and you did not provide this answer (essentially saying "go look at the docs"), I don't believe this is a good answer. Please edit with the difference between the two.

Answer (score 6):

find() and exec() serve two different purposes. 
The find() method is a database READ operation enabling function. It is
present in both the native mongodb driver for node, as well as the Mongoose library which internally uses the mongodb drivers and is especially useful for imposing a fixed schema.
Now, in mongodb driver, if you use `find(query)`, the query is automatically executed where as in mongoose it wouldn't. We need helper functions/ callbacks to get the operation to execute.
exec is one such helper function.
It goes something like: `myPlaylist.findOne({'singer':'Adam Levine'}).exec()`
Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for convenience.
If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.

So, you could do a `myPlaylist.findOne({'singer':'Adam Levine'}).then()` but that would return a Mongoose/BlueBird (yet another library) promise and a typical JavaScript one.

Note: exec() takes an optional callback function. It's only when you do not use a callback that you get back a Promise.

Comment: So to get the fully-fledged promise i would do
`myPlaylist.findOne({'singer':'Adam Levine'}).exec().then(...) ?`
Or I must use the bluebird library for that? @sushmita-mallick

Comment: Yes, it would return a fully fledged promise if you do it this way @O'DaneBrissett

Comment: Would it be necessary to use aync/await?