# Mongoose insertMany().exec() returning a TypeError

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

The following function is called by an async/await function and therefore I need a real Promise to be returned from Mongoose hence the use of ".exec()" per the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do).

```
// where data is an array of documents
function insertNewResults(data) {
    return Model.insertMany(data).exec();
}
```

Doing so gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Model.insertMany(...).exec is not a function
>       at insertNewResults

If I remove exec(), I'm able to insertMany without any issues. My other queries using exec() don't seem to be throwing any errors, which makes it all the more perplexing.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

**Edit 1: Below is my Schema code**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: { type: Date, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    result: { type: String, required: true }
}, { usePushEach: true });

schema.index(
    { date: -1 }
);
mongoose.model('Model', schema);
```

Comment: Could you post your schma code

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet just edited my post by adding schema code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it's explained in the reference, `exec()` may be needed for methods that return queries because [queries are not promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises). The reference also lists [methods that return queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

```
Model.deleteMany()
Model.deleteOne()
Model.find()
Model.findById()
Model.findByIdAndDelete()
Model.findByIdAndRemove()
Model.findByIdAndUpdate()
Model.findOne()
Model.findOneAndDelete()
Model.findOneAndRemove()
Model.findOneAndUpdate()
Model.replaceOne()
Model.updateMany()
Model.updateOne()
```

`insertMany` isn't one of them, [it returns a promise right away](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany).

It should be:

```
function insertNewResults(data) {
    return Model.insertMany(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Would you happen to know why some Mongoose queries return promises and others return queries? Seems a little strange to me that this inconsistency exists

Comment: They return queries when there's something to query (read, update, delete operations) and return promises when there's nothing to query (create operations). Depending on how you use results, you may return a query straight away and don't bother with exec.