# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON node js

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

when i try to get my api via postman i have this error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
```

i use mongoose and express

```js
const express = require('express')
const Rent = require('../model/rent')
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

route = express()

route.use(express.json());

route.get('/rent', (req,res) => {
    const rents = Rent.find();
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rents))
})

module.exports = route
```

if i delete JSON.stringify i have the same problem 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Rent.find();` is probably returning a `Promise` and that is what you are trying to stringify there. What you could probably do is `await` the `Promise` for the actual value that is needed. This should do the trick:

```js
const express = require('express')
const Rent = require('../model/rent')
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

route = express()

route.use(express.json());

route.get('/rent', async (req,res) => {          // Made the controller into an `async` function to be able to use the `await` keyword
    const rents = await Rent.find();             // Await the Promise
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rents))
})

module.exports = route
```

Comment: @AdamCole is your code the same with the asker's?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION #1**

1. Calling `find` on model `Rent` will return a Promise.
2. We need to `await` for the Promise to resolve or get rejected in case of some error.
3. Always put `async\await` code inside a `try-catch` block.

```js
const express = require('express')
const Rent = require('../model/rent')

route = express()

route.use(express.json());

route.get('/rent', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rents = await Rent.find().exec();
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rents));
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({error: error.message});
  }  
})

module.exports = route;
```

**SOLUTION #2**: If you want the result in JSON format. This how I would code.

```
* node_modules
* app.js
* db.js
* src
  - routes
    - api_router.js
```

File `path\to\project\app.js`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

const db = require("./db");

var apiRouter = require('./src/routes/api_router');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

File `path\to\project\db.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/backend_app";
const DB_OPTIONS = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true
}

(async function () {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB_URI, DB_OPTIONS);
    console.log("MONGOOSE: Connected to the database!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("MONGOOSE ERROR");
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

File `path\to\project\src\routes\api_router.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Rent = require('../models/country_model')

router.get('/rent', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rents = await Rent.find().exec();
    res.status(200).json({ data: rents });           // <- Check this line.
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });  // <- Check this line.
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Why `find().exec()`?**

`find().exec()` on mongoose function will return an "real" Promise object. [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do#answer-31550321)

Comment: Please update your question with contents of this `../model/rent` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
route.get('/rent', (req,res) => {          
    Rent.find({}).then((rents)=>{
        res.send(rents)
    })           
})
```