# node.js & mongodb: await collection.find vs. collection.find.exec for async

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I recently came across the node.js/mongodb pattern which as I understand returns a promise.
`collection.find({ ... }).exec()`

I use in my code:

```
await collection.find({ ... })
```

How are these different? Should I be using:

```
await collection.find({ ... }).exec()
```

Here's what I currently use and it works w/o issue:

```
router.get('/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.sub).select('email');

        if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ "status": "error", "message": "This user no longer exists." });

        res.json({ "status": "success", "user": user });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

Comment: It does, but what's confusing is that my routine works perfectly and I don't use ".exec()" and await. I'll update the question w/my exact code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mongoose queries are composed but not necessarily run immediately.They return a query object that you can use to add or chain other queries to it and then execute it all together.

Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a `.then()` function and `async/await` as a convenience.. `.exec()` can be used instead of `.then()` too for a callback.

**Which one you should use?**

- `await collection.find({ ... })`
- `await collection.find({ ... }).exec()`

**Answer** : Both are fine.

Both does have some functionality so you can use any of the two as per your convenience.

However, if you use `.exec()` it will give you better stack traces in case of errors/exceptions.
More information [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).