first executing the code that returns a promise, performing operations on it and then awaiting at last
class APIFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryString) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryString = queryString;
  }

  filter() {
    const queryObj = { ...this.queryString };
    const excludedFields = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields'];
    excludedFields.forEach(el => delete queryObj[el]);

    // 1B) Advanced filtering
    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, match => `$${match}`);

    this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

    return this;
  }
}
const features = new APIFeatures(Tour.find(), req.query).filter();
const tours = await features.query;


when we write Tour.find() it returns a promise which is saved to query variable of APIFeatures object. this variable maybe in promise pending state is used by filter function and a method find on the result is invoked in this.query.find. After that we are awaiting the features.query which gives the final result. Can anyone tell me why we are awaiting at last and not when we write Tours.find() and whereever query is being used?

"Tour.find() returns a promise" - no it doesn't. It seems to return a query object. filter then calls this.query.find(…). Awaiting the query then executes it.

@Bergi "Awaiting the query then executes it. " it executes what? can you explain better

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v4.1/fundamentals/promises/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191878/node-js-mongodb-await-collection-find-vs-collection-find-exec-for-async

@Bergi sorry i cant understand anything from those links. can you explain "Awaiting the query then executes it. "what does executing the query means

Assuming Tour is a mongoose model, the Tour.find() returns a Query object.  The APIFeatures.filter function replaces the query string in the query object, and returns both the modified query object and the query string.  When you await the query object, it calls that object exec method. If you awaited Tour.find() where it is written, you would not have an opportunity to set the query before the request is sent to the server.

@joe " If you awaited Tour.find() where it is written, you would not have an opportunity to set the query before the request is sent to the server". This is all happening after the request is sent to the server. Can you explain it better?

I'm pretty sure this is not happening on the database server.

@joe except  Tour.find()  rest is happening on application server including processing the query string. What is the difference if we await the query later or await Tour.find() in beginning?

If you await Tour.find() the application server will submit the query to the database server, and will return an array containing every document in the tours collection.  If you then pass that to the APIFeatures constructor, it will be an array, not a query object, and will not have a find method, so this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)) will throw an error.

@Joe sorry but if Tour.find() doesnt return a promise, why do we await it. Tour.find() is an asynchronous operation. so what if query object  hasnt been returned when we use this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)), that would throw error. can you explain better?

Mongoose is open source, take a look at the Query object, you can see how it acts like a promise and how it doesn't
