# In Mongoose Model.find() and Model.find().exec() produce the same result. So why bother using Model.find().exec()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, save, exec

I noticed that `Model.find()` seems to produce the same outcome as `Model.find().exec()`.  Both seem to retrieve the appropriate record/document as illustrated in the following two snippets of code:

```
//without exec
export const getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let mongoDocument = await User.find({name: "OrphanAnnie"})
        res.status(200).json(mongoDocument);  
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err) 
    }
}

//with exec
export const getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let mongoDocument = await User.find({name: "OrphanAnnie"}).exec()
        res.status(200).json(mongoDocument);  
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err) 
    }
}
```

Which is the recommended approach? In [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do) the post suggests that with `exec()` a Mongoose query can be built without using callback syntax.  But since the query seems to work without using `exec()` at all why bother using it?

Comment: Only very imperfectly.  That post suggests that exec() allows you to execute a Mongoose query without a callback.  But it seems like one can execute the Mongoose query even without exec().

Comment: BTW, one can also execute the query this way:  export const getUser = (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ name: "OrphanAnnie" })
        .then(function (user) {
            return res.json(user);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        });
}  But even while this works, it doesn't clarify what the exec does when using the await syntax approach....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose have explained the difference of both in [promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await?),

> *There are two alternatives for using `await` with queries:*
>
> - *`await Band.find();`*
> - *`await Band.find().exec();`*
>
> ***As far as functionality is concerned, these two are equivalent. However, we recommend using [`.exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) because that gives you better stack traces.***

With the example:

```
const doc = await Band.find({ name: "Guns N' Roses" }); // works

const badId = 'this is not a valid id';
try {
  await Band.find({ _id: badId });
} catch (err) {
  // Without `exec()`, the stack trace does **not** include the
  // calling code. Below is the stack trace:
  //
  // CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "this is not a valid id" at path "_id" for model "band-promises"
  //   at new CastError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
  //   at model.Query.exec (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4331:21)
  //   at model.Query.Query.then (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4423:15)
  //   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  err.stack;
}

try {
  await Band.find({ _id: badId }).exec();
} catch (err) {
  // With `exec()`, the stack trace includes where in your code you
  // called `exec()`. Below is the stack trace:
  //
  // CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "this is not a valid id" at path "_id" for model "band-promises"
  //   at new CastError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
  //   at model.Query.exec (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4331:21)
  //   at Context.<anonymous> (/app/test/index.test.js:138:42)
  //   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  err.stack;
}
```

---

Other as well: [**Queries are not promises**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises):

> *Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a `.then()` function for co and `async/await` as a convenience. **If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the `.exec()` function.***

```
const query = Band.find({name: "Guns N' Roses"});
assert.ok(!(query instanceof Promise));

// A query is not a fully-fledged promise, but it does have a `.then()`.
query.then(function (docs) {
  // use docs
});

// `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
const promise = query.exec();
assert.ok(promise instanceof Promise);

promise.then(function (docs) {
  // use docs
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  This clarifies things.  Thank you very much.  A big thumbs up to you!  And nice sleuthing in the Mongoose docs.  If you simply search on "Exec" as i did in the Mongoose search field the page you cite AFAIK does not appear.  Is that a problem with the docs?  Or are you using some other logic to find that info?