# MongoDB User.findOne({email:email})

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**findOne return null Always**

I have "user(hello@gmail.com)" data in the database but User.findOne returns null always. Please Help me. I have a node running on background but it gives me null . **req.body** gives the email that im passing but findOne isnot working. **User.create** is working fine. but search queries like  **find,findById,findOne** is not working. SomeOne please help me.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have a unique name'],
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 8,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have a unique name'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  }
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

exports.getTest=async (req,res)=>{
    const {email} = req.body  // returns "hello@gmail.com"
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    console.log(user) //returns null
    res.json({
     
        status:"success",
        data:{
            user
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You probably have a space or mismatch in your email field. Your syntax looks correct and you do not need exec(). Triple check all assumptions as these are the root of all evil.

Comment: I was told `.exec()` made Mongoose requests asynchronous, I could never check if this was true

Comment: this is my second week trying to find my bug. i couldnot find.thats why i need your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents should save `active: true`  in the database. but instead, I'm saving every document as false as the default value. So, this is my answer if anyone in the future finds it useful let me know. Take care and goodbye

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your issue lies in the first two lines of your test?

```
const {email} = req.body  // returns "hello@gmail.com"
const user = await User.findOne({email})
```

If your `req.body` just returns the email string, then maybe your query isn't in the right JSON format?

Are you sure that the query actually ends up being `User.findOne({email: "hello@gmail.com"})` instead of just `User.findOne("hello@gmail.com")`?

Also not sure if you need `exec()` at the end, [but it *does* execute the query and return a Promise...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

Comment: ```User.findOne({email: "hello@gmail.com"})``` yes sir .it takes like that i checked million times. the queries is not working i dont know why