# What is the best way to promisify library in js?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

In one of my previous posts I realised I needed to promisify (turn a callback into a new promise) a npm module to make clean error handling. Problem is, the more I started to think about the organisation of promisifing a library the more it dawned on me that it could easily become a big fat mess. How should I access the promisified function, in what object? Could I maybe replace the original library functions with the new promisified functions? Should I just create a new object for the promisified functions? Example:

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const { MongoClient } = mongodb;

//Promisifing MongoClient.connect(), and storing it into connectPr into the original library
mongodb.MongoClient.connectPr = function (url) {
  const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, options, (error, client) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(client);
    });
  });

  return promise;
};

//Exporting whole module with added functions
module.exports = mongodb;
```

What I am doing here is just modifing the original library and adding the new function `connectPr` into it. Then I export it and use it like this in another file:

```
const mongodb = require("./helperMongoDB");
const { MongoClient } = mongodb;

const connectionURL = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
const databaseName = "tasker";

//Using new connectPr function
(async function () {
  const client = await MongoClient.connectPr(connectionURL);
  const db = client.db(databaseName);

  db.collection("tasks").insertOne(
      {
        description: "Clean the house",
        completed: true,
      },
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }
  
      console.log(result.ops);
    }
  );
})();
```

As u can see I can still use all the original properties from the module and I can also use my connectPr function. This works but its nothing pretty. I am sure that if I worked in a team of people that most of them would be pretty confused on why I am not requiring the library normally and why it is hidden somwhere in a helper file. What is the standard on doing this kind of thing? Is promisifing a callback function even a practise?

Comment: Hi, I believe it is a practice, especially for legacy code revamp/refactor time. It is not a problem your function is hided in library, but with proper, more straightforward architecture (naming, file & directory structure, DRY/SOLID, comments/docblocks) you could help others to work with.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original ?

Comment: @JeremyThille - TIL - nice

Comment: The mongodb client already exposes promises. Just leave out the callback arguments and the methods will return a promise. For example: [connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#.connect): *"**Returns**: Promise if no callback passed"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to first check that the asynchronous API does not already provide a promise interface. In your question you give the example of mongodb. This node API's asynchronous methods will return a promise when the callback argument is not provided.

For instance, take the [connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) method. The documentation says:

> #### Returns:
>
> Promise if no callback passed

So in an `async` function body you can write:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, options);
```

In case of the Mongoose library (built on top of the Node MongoDb driver API), when using *query* methods, you may need to chain an `.exec()` call, as is discussed in the answers to [What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550321/5459839).

Any asynchronous library that wants to remain on track, will have a promise API included. If really this is not the case, look at Node's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)