# MongoDB .find() doesn't return the right data

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, mongoose-schema

I'm trying get the data from mongodb but whenever i try to use `find()` I get following response. I'm very new to Mongo and just don't know why this is happening. Also this code is written in TypeScript and used to code a Discord bot.

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: null,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'verifiedUsers',
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'verifiedUsers',
    collectionName: 'verifiedUsers',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: {},
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 0,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: false,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [],
      _listening: false
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: true,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { verifiedUsers },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: { ign: [Object], memberid: [Object] },
    paths: {
      ign: [SchemaString],
      memberid: [SchemaString],
      _id: [ObjectId],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]
    },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      ign: [Object],
      memberid: [Object],
      _id: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    mapPaths: [],
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: {},
    options: {
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      _id: true,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: true,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: Collection {
      collection: null,
```

This is the code I'm using:
**Schema:**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const verifiedUsers = new mongoose.Schema({
    ign: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    memberid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})

export default mongoose.model('verifiedUsers', verifiedUsers, 'verifiedUsers')
```

**get Verfifed Users:**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import verifiedUsers from './schemas/verified-users'

client.on('ready', async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(
        process.env.mongo_uri || '',
        {
            keepAlive: true
    })
})

async function getVerifiedUsers() {
    console.log(verifiedUsers.find())
}
getVerifiedUsers()
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to call `.exec()`.

Check [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550321/5640517).

Maybe someone else can explain why it was decided to do it like this instead of awaiting `.find()` to get the data.