# Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback can some one help me out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, callback

```
List.findOne({name:tagname},function(err,fidlist){
    if(!err){
        if(!fidlist){
            console.log("doesnt exist");
        }
        else {
            console.log("exist");
        }
    }
});
```

How to fix the code showing Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback can some one help me out.

Comment: try `const fidList = await List.findOne({name:tagname});`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne) (for version 7) `findOne` returns a query, not a promise. Looks like you need to `exec()` the query, which then returns a promise.

Comment: can you make changes in code

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer can help you understand better: [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)

To get the same functionality of your code with `exec()`, you can do this:

```
List.findOne({ name: tagname })
  .exec()
  .then((err, fidlist) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("something went wrong");
    }
    if (fidlist) {
      console.log("exists");
    } else {
      console.log("doesn't exists");
    }
  });
```