# .populate() method is not working in mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm using Nextjs to create an ecommerce application. I have a `reviews` array made of objects, which contains a property `reviewBy`.

I want to populate this `reviewBy` property like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a1"
  },
  "name": "Allover Plants Print Square Neck Knot Front Dress",
  "description": "Allover Plants Print Square Neck Knot Front Dress",
  "brand": "Boho",
  "slug": "Allover-Plants-Print-Square-Neck-Knot-Front-Dress",
  "category": {
    "$oid": "62c46ff0062128444ad59193"
  },
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "$oid": "62c46ffd062128444ad59199"
    }
  ],
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "Style",
      "value": "Boho",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a2"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Pattern Type",
      "value": "Plants, All Over Print",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a3"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Details",
      "value": "Knot",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a4"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Type",
      "value": "A Line",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a5"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Neckline",
      "value": "Square Neck",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a6"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Sleeve Length",
      "value": "Short Sleeve",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a7"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Sleeve Type",
      "value": "Puff Sleeve",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a8"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Waist Line",
      "value": "High Waist",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591a9"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Hem Shaped",
      "value": "Flared",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591aa"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Length",
      "value": "Long",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591ab"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Fit Type",
      "value": "Regular Fit",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591ac"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Fabric",
      "value": "Non-Stretch",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591ad"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Material",
      "value": "Polyester",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591ae"
      }
    }
  ],
  "questions": [],
  "subProducts": [
    {
      "sku": "sw2206138988536738",
      "discount": 0,
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041164/products/j9h8giisorvqwnxgy6lx.webp",
          "public_url": "products/j9h8giisorvqwnxgy6lx"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041168/products/tpwwbcdjxdzk1qok7jqu.webp",
          "public_url": "products/tpwwbcdjxdzk1qok7jqu"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041171/products/lopvo38miankt6j0usaz.webp",
          "public_url": "products/lopvo38miankt6j0usaz"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041176/products/mjrdih9alzizp5lkb0ty.webp",
          "public_url": "products/mjrdih9alzizp5lkb0ty"
        }
      ],
      "description_images": [],
      "color": {
        "color": "#ecd297",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041179/products/ac3homl0yeimydql5rq4.webp"
      },
      "sizes": [
        {
          "size": "S",
          "qty": 15,
          "price": 17,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591b0"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "M",
          "qty": 1414,
          "price": 19,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591b1"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "L",
          "qty": 0,
          "price": 21,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591b2"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "XL",
          "qty": 1423,
          "price": 28,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591b3"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c4711c062128444ad591af"
      }
    },
    {
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045381/products/qbwsyo2xg26zxyygtuzs.webp",
          "public_url": "products/qbwsyo2xg26zxyygtuzs"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045385/products/fxuhya9s4usojgdfune9.webp",
          "public_url": "products/fxuhya9s4usojgdfune9"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045389/products/acscvdlnkyt8r7kifsw5.webp",
          "public_url": "products/acscvdlnkyt8r7kifsw5"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045392/products/suok4nz4ocdmegkzmqvs.webp",
          "public_url": "products/suok4nz4ocdmegkzmqvs"
        }
      ],
      "sku": "vc22142578988545614",
      "description_images": [],
      "color": {
        "color": "#dac4ac",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045396/products/ouh3i2klgrmwluexm3q9.webp"
      },
      "sizes": [
        {
          "size": "M",
          "qty": 1456,
          "price": 15,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c481967d2df7b52aa1f9e3"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "L",
          "qty": 1700,
          "price": 21,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "62c481967d2df7b52aa1f9e4"
          }
        }
      ],
      "discount": 10,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c481967d2df7b52aa1f9e2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2022-07-05T17:13:00.324Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2022-07-09T09:44:46.823Z"
  },
  "__v": 17,
  "numReviews": 5,
  "rating": 3.5,
  "refundPolicy": "30 days",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "reviewBy": {
        "$oid": "62b33178fbcc6f0282db0606"
      },
      "rating": 1,
      "review": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "size": "S",
      "style": {
        "color": "#dac4ac",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045396/products/ouh3i2klgrmwluexm3q9.webp"
      },
      "fit": "Small",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657145489/reviews/whcchkvkbd4dypptoccx.webp",
          "public_url": "reviews/whcchkvkbd4dypptoccx"
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c6089247a21fb57bb8b234"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-06T22:11:30.149Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-09T09:44:46.559Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "reviewBy": {
        "$oid": "62c69fc002820c409dcce9ea"
      },
      "rating": 4,
      "review": "i like it  a lot but a bit large for me for size L",
      "size": "L",
      "style": {
        "color": "#dac4ac",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045396/products/ouh3i2klgrmwluexm3q9.webp"
      },
      "fit": "Large",
      "images": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c6a03702820c409dcce9f2"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T08:58:31.646Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T08:58:31.646Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "reviewBy": {
        "$oid": "62a22b5cd0e120974f5c866e"
      },
      "rating": 5,
      "review": "amaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazing",
      "size": "L",
      "style": {
        "color": "#dac4ac",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657045396/products/ouh3i2klgrmwluexm3q9.webp"
      },
      "fit": "Large",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657189685/reviews/i6wmqtwnjcolkguit6qi.webp",
          "public_url": "reviews/i6wmqtwnjcolkguit6qi"
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c6b13402820c409dccea08"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T10:11:00.304Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T10:28:07.389Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "reviewBy": {
        "$oid": "62a22d98d0e120974f5c8671"
      },
      "rating": 2.5,
      "review": "aaaaaaaa",
      "size": "S",
      "style": {
        "color": "#ecd297",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041179/products/ac3homl0yeimydql5rq4.webp"
      },
      "fit": "True to size",
      "images": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c6d15802820c409dccea3d"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T12:28:08.226Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T12:30:52.277Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "reviewBy": {
        "$oid": "62a2281cd0e120974f5c866c"
      },
      "rating": 5,
      "review": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
      "size": "S",
      "style": {
        "color": "#ecd297",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1657041179/products/ac3homl0yeimydql5rq4.webp"
      },
      "fit": "True to size",
      "images": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c6d29602820c409dccea5e"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T12:33:26.719Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-07-07T12:33:26.719Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "shipping": "2"
}
```

so, i written code like this:

```
  let product: any = await Product.findOne({ slug })
    .populate({ path: "category", model: Category })
    .populate({ path: "subCategories._id", model: SubCategory })
    .populate({ path: "reviews.reviewBy", model: User })
    .lean();
```

So as per my instructor, he told to use "reviews.reviewBy". but it was throwing me `null` in that place.

Please help me. because iam newbie here. If you find this as stupid question please just ignore it. it's beginner mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to each subdocument you want to populate in your `Product` schema as described in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). For example, your schema should resemble:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //...
   //...
   slug: String,
   category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category' //< Make sure you have a reference to Category
   },
   subCategories:[{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'SubCategory' //< Make sure you have a reference to SubCategory
   }],
   //...
   //...
   reviews:[{
      reviewBy:{
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User' //< Make sure you have a reference to User
      },
      //...
      //...
   }]
   //...
   //...
});
```

This will make your `populate` methods work correctly like so:

```
const product = await Product.findOne({ slug })
   .populate({ path: "category", model: Category })
   .populate({ path: "subCategories", model: SubCategory })
   .populate({ path: "reviews.reviewBy", model: User })
   .lean();
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for spending your valuable time, i have product Schema like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hertz-cy9ft9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You're welcome. The schemas in the link look excellent.

Answer (score 0):

```
         let product = await Product.findOne({ slug })
         .populate({ path: "category", model: Category })
         .populate({ path: "subCategories._id", model: SubCategory })
         .populate({ path: "reviews.reviewBy", model: User })
         .lean()
         .exec();
```

I think you are missing exec() method at the end that's why it's not working. The exec() method triggers the execution of the query and returns a promise that resolves with the query result.

Comment: The `exec()` added to the query has made no material difference to the OPs problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do) question for an explanation on when to use `exec()` and what the result is.